# Accessing data-* in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with the following format :

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" 

data-bind='attr : {"name":"John"}'></div>
```

I am trying to change the name from "**John**" to "**Johnny**". I am trying to do this in this way :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($( "div" ).data( "options"));

});
```

This outputs me as :

```
attr : {"name" : "John"}
```

I tried accessing considering it as in json format like :
`alert($( "div" ).data( "options").attr)` but it is *`undefined`* .

Is it in a string format and should I asign it to some variable , use regex expression and change the string format?
How do I change it using jquery?

Comment: I think you're confusing an actual object and a stringified representation of that thing. That's like confusing a picture of a person with the actual person. a picture is no person, a string is no object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using correct format,  *use*

```
<div data-options='{ "attr" : {"name":"John"}}'></div>
```

```js
var div = $("div");
var data = div.data("options")
console.log(data.attr)

//update name
setTimeout(() => {
  data.attr.name = 'Satpal';
  div.data("options", data);

  data = div.data("options")
  console.log(data.attr);
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-options='{ "attr" : {"name":"John"}}'></div>
```

Comment: the html div is in the same format which I have shared and its an old and running application . I just need to modify the name .

Comment: So, You cant change the HTML to correct the structure

Comment: No I cannot change it . I will check with the original developer anyways . Is the html definitely wrong?Because I need to communicate with the original developer

Comment: I apoloigize for the confusion , its a knockout data-bind attribute and not a html5 attribute.